# Is the following ratio of gamma functions increasing: $\frac{\Gamma(2n - \frac{1.25506n}{\ln n})}{\Gamma(n)^2}$?

Tags: derivatives, inequality, gamma-function, digamma-function

For $n > 1$, is the following ratio of gamma functions increasing:  $\dfrac{\Gamma(2n - \frac{1.25506n}{\ln n})}{\Gamma(n)^2}$

I suspect that it is at some point where $n > 1$.

I would like figure out if the derivative is increasing or not and if increasing, from what point?

I had hoped that this [series ψ](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.7#E6) would be sufficient with:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\ln\Gamma(x)) = \frac{\psi(x)}{dx} = -\gamma + \sum_{k=0}^\infty(\frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{k + x})$$

So, my goal would be to show that the following is increasing for $n \ge 1$:
$$\ln\Gamma(2n - \dfrac{1.25506n}{\ln n}) - 2\ln\Gamma(n)$$

This got me to:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln\Gamma(2n - \dfrac{1.25506n}{\ln n}) - 2\ln\Gamma(n)\right) = \frac{\psi(2n - \frac{1.25506n}{\ln n})}{2 - \frac{1.25506}{\ln n} + \frac{1.25506}{\ln^2 n}} - 2\psi(n)$$

When I tried to apply the last part, I was at a loss.

How would I complete the argument to determine whether there exists a real $n > 0$ where the function is strictly increasing?

---

Edit 1:

I had a thought.  Does the following logic work?

An easier problem is:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\ln\Gamma(2n) - 2\ln\Gamma(n)) = \frac{\psi(2n)}{2} - 2\psi(n) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{2n}\right) > 0$$

If I change this to some real constant $c < 1$:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\ln\Gamma(n(2-c)) - 2\ln\Gamma(n)) = \frac{\psi(n(2-c))}{2-c} - 2\psi(n) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n(2-c)}\right) > 0$$

Would it now be sufficient to complete the argument by showing that for $n \ge 4$:

$$\frac{1.25506}{\ln n} < 1$$

and showing that:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1.25506}{\ln n}\right) = -\frac{1.25506}{n\ln^2(n)}$$ which is decreasing at $n\ge 4$.

Is this enough to establish the conclusion?

---

Edit 2:

To be clear, it should be:

$$\frac{\Gamma(2n - \frac{1.25506n}{\ln n})}{[\Gamma(n)]^2}$$

Comment: Where does this mysterious $1.25506$ come from?

Comment: It is the upper bound for $\pi(n)$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities)

Comment: Is it $\Gamma(n^2)$ or $\Gamma(n)^2$? Your title and the initial line say the former but later when taking the logarithm you say its the latter. I suspect a typo because the former is easy to show it goes quickly to zero.

Comment: It should be $\Gamma(n)^2$.  I will fix it where I say $\Gamma(n^2)$.  Thanks for calling this out.

Comment: Try taking the limit as $n$ goes to infinity and using Stirlings approximation. Its still difficult, but it at least transforms to an ugly limit that wolfram alpha should be able to solve.

Comment: Is the approach in Edit 1 above invalid? I'll assume that it is based on your comment. If you can help me to understand what's wrong with it, that will be helpful. I'll work with Stirling's Approximation to see if I can get that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f[n_] := Gamma[2 n - 1.25506 n/Log[n]]/Gamma[n]^2
Plot[f[n], {n, 2, 300}]
```

[image]

Minimum zone, enlarged:

[image]

For integer $n$, minimal value of 0.06628307572263 is achieved for $n=107$.