# Is this a valid approach to proving the Sylvester-Schur Theorem

Tags: number-theory, inequality, binomial-coefficients, solution-verification, gamma-function

I have recently been asking a lot of questions regarding the Gamma Function and a well-known upper bound of the prime counting function.  I really appreciate everyone's assistance in helping me to better reason with the Gamma Function.

I wanted to also check if my approach to proving the [Sylvester-Schur Theorem](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~shorey/newton.pdf) makes sense.  I have long found Paul Erdős's classic [paper](https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1934-01.pdf) on the theorem especially difficult to follow and wondered if an approach based on the properties of the [Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) and the inequality from [Rosser and Schoenfeld](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255631807) would also work.

Is the following a valid approach to proving the Sylvester-Schur Theorem?

**Sylvester-Schur Theorem**:  For integers: $x > 1, k \ge 2x$, there exists a prime $p > x$ that divides ${{k}\choose{x}}$.

Here is the argument:

(1)  For $x \ge 631$, the following inequality holds:

$$\frac{\Gamma\left(2x+1-\frac{1.255506x}{\ln x}\right)}{\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(x+1)} > 1$$

- The value at $631$ can be checked $\approx 1.0018$
- This function is increasing at $x \ge 631$  [See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3684456/48606), or [graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3672491/48606)]

Note:  I am still not 100% clear on the analysis that it is increasing.  Integrand gave an answer which was very helpful (see above).

(2) Assume that Sylvester-Schur is false.  That there exists an integer $k$ such that no prime $p > x$ divides ${{k} \choose {x}}$

(3)  Then, the following is true where lcm$(a,b,c,\dots)$ is the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of $a, b, c, \dots$:

$$\text{lcm}(k-x+1, k-x+2, \dots, k) < \frac{k!}{[k-\pi(x)]!}$$

Note:  This analysis stems from 2 observations

- If $t$ is the maximum power of a prime $p$ that divides $k-x+c$, then $p^t \le k-x+c$
- If $p^t > x$, then $p^t$ can only divide one element in $k-x+1, k-x+2, \dots, k$ (otherwise, $p^t | (k-x+a) - (k-x+b) = a - b < x$)

(4)  From properties of Least Common Multiples and Binomial Coefficients (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas)), it can be shown that:

$$\text{lcm}(k-x+1, k-x+2, \dots, k) \ge {k \choose x}$$

(5)  But then:

$$\frac{k!}{[k-\pi(x)]!} \ge  {k \choose x}$$

Which, when using the Rosser and Schoenfeld upper bound for $\pi(x)$, leads to:

$${k \choose x}<\frac{k!}{[k-\pi(x)]!} < \frac{\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma\left(k + 1 - \frac{1.25506x}{\ln x}\right)} <\frac{k!}{[k - \left\lfloor\frac{1.25506x}{\ln x}\right\rfloor]!}$$

(6)  But this contradicts step(1) since:

$$\frac{\Gamma\left(k+1-\frac{1.255506x}{\ln x}\right)}{\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(x+1)} \ge \frac{\Gamma\left(2x+1-\frac{1.255506x}{\ln x}\right)}{\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(x+1)} > 1$$

- After multiplying $\dfrac{\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma\left(k + 1 - \frac{1.25506x}{\ln x}\right)} $ to both sides:

$$\frac{\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma\left(k + 1 - \frac{1.25506x}{\ln x}\right)} < \frac{\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(x+1)} = {k \choose x}$$

Please let me know if there is any problem with any step in this argument or whether there is a simpler way to make the same argument.

Comment: There is something very attractive about this proof but I'm struggling to understand your step 3. Intuitively I would expect the inequality the other way around because $x$ is so much bigger than $\pi(x)$. Suppose that $\pi(x)$ is only 5. The $x$ can be a huge number in comparison, like 12. Now you are saying that if I pick 12 consecutive numbers somewhere high up in the number line (ending in $k$) there won't be 5 coprime integers among them? It seems weird... Also: do you claim that this always hold or only for the special counterfactual $x$ and $k$ coming from the negation of Sylv-Schur?

Comment: The standard argument is that lcm$(x-k+1, x-k+2, \dots, k) < k^{\pi(x)}$.  My step is an improvement because each power of $p$ can only divide one specific number.  Does that help to make it clear?  Sylvester-Schur is already proven.  I am trying to show an alternative argument.  If you pick 12 consecutive numbers, at least one will be divisible by a prime larger than $11$.  That's all I am saying.

Comment: I did want to follow up on your question about 5 co-prime integers which I think is vey interesting.  I did the calculations and within my argument it does not show more than $1$ prime is necessary.  If you change the equation to $k + 1 - \dfrac{1.25506x}{\ln x} - n$, for larger $x$, it is possible to show that there must be at least $n$ distinct primes that are divisors.  You will need to get to a larger $x$ before $n = x - \pi(x)$.  I have another argument [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/262400/15915) about the size of $x$ if you are interested.

Comment: Yes the mathoverflow post is very interesting! Still I'm confused about step 3. Suppose that $k = 109$ and $x = 12$. Now on the right hand side we have $109*108*107*106*105$. This 'simplifies' to $(109*108*107*53*35)*(2*3)$. On the left hand side we have $lcd(109, 108, 107, 106, 105, 104, 103, 102, 101, 100, 99, 98)$. Without computing anything we can see that this is at least as big as $lcd(109, 108, 107, 106, 105, 104)$, which simplifies to $109*108*107*53*35*26$. Since $26 > 2*3$ we have that the left hand side of step 3 is BIGGER rather than smaller than the right hand side for these x, k.

Comment: Perhaps this is because $x = 12, k = 109$ is not a counter example to Sylvest-Schur, but I don't see where you use that in the proof. Somehow step 3 seems to be written as if it should work for all $x, k$.

Comment: The big difference is the assumption in step (2).  If there is no prime greater than $12$, then lcm$(98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109)$ can only consider powers of $2,3,5,7,11$.  If it is higher, then the contradiction is already shown.  Let's assume it is not higher.  Then there is at most 1 power of $11^a > 12$, 1 power of $7^b > 12$, etc.  The product of these powers will be less than $\dfrac{109!}{(109-5)!}$.  You are calculating a higher lcm because you are allowing primes greater than $12$.  It is reinforcing the argument as I see it.

Comment: Right! I understand it now, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I now that I understand step 3 I'd say its a valid proof.

EDITED IN LATER:

If you don't mind I write down here an alternative proof of the inequality in step 3 to help myself understand how it uses the assumption of step 2.

Let $A$ be the set of $x$ numbers $\{k - x + 1, k - x + 2, \ldots, k\}$ and let $P = \{p_1, \ldots, p_n\}$ be the set of distinct primes dividing at least one element of $A$. Finally let numbers $t_1, \ldots, t_n$ defined by the requirement that $p_i^{t_i}$ is the *highest* power of $p_i$ dividing an element of $A$.

By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic we have that $\gcd(A) = \prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{t_i}$. Moreover for every $p_i \in P$ there is at least one $a \in A$ such that $p_i^{t_i} | a$. Now you state that in the special case that $p_i^{t_i} > x$ this $a$ is unique, but I don't see how that is helpful since we don't have much control over the size of the $p_i^{t_i}$. However that is no problem.

For every $p_i \in P$ I just pick (by some arbitrary process) an element $\phi(p_i) \in A$ such that $p_i^{t_i}|\phi(p_i)$.

Now we have this map $\phi$ from the $n$-element set $P$ to the $x$-element set $A$ that is well defined (though not necessarily injective) and we denote by $B \subset A$ its image: $B = \phi(P)$. We write $m$ for the number of elements in $B$, so $m \leq \min(n, x)$.

Now since the elements of $P$ are distinct, the fundamental theorem of arithmetic tells us that whenever we have that $\phi(p_i) = \phi(p_j)$ we have that $(p_i^{t_i}p_j^{t_j})|\phi(p_i)$.

It follows that:

$$\left(\prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{t_i} \right) | \left( \prod_{b \in B} b \right)$$

On the left hand side we have $\gcd(A)$. On the right hand side we have a product of $m$ distinct elements of $A$ (namely: the $m$ distinct elements of $B$). It follows that the right hand side, and hence the left hand side as well, are smaller than or equal to the *largest* product of $m$ distinct elements from $A$, which are of course the elements $k - m + 1, \ldots, k$. In other words we find:

$$\gcd(A) \leq k!/(k - m)!$$

This is very close to the inequality in step (3), all we need to show in order to find that that inequality holds as well, is $m \leq \pi(x)$. And since $m \leq n$ for that it suffices to show that $n \leq \pi(x)$ and for that of course it suffices to show that each $p_i \leq x$, so that's what we are going to do.

**CLAIM:** Under assumption of step 2, every prime $p$ dividing an element of $A$ satisfies $p \leq x$.

Proof by contradiction: assume that $p > x$ and $p|a$ for some $a \in A$. It follows trivially that $p|\prod A$. Moreover since $p$ is prime and $p > x$ we have by Euclid's lemma that $p$ does *not* divide $x!$. It follows (again by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic) that $p$ divides $(\prod A) / x!$ $=$ $\binom{k}{x}$.

We already used the assumption $p > x$ once in the proof but now we'll use it again: $p > x$ and $p|\binom{k}{x}$ together contradict step (2). The claim in bold (and hence inequality of step 3) follow.

Comment: I keep thinking though there must be an easier way to handle step 1 than what happens in the answer to the other question. Perhaps I find one and come back to it...

Comment: That would be awesome.  I am still working through step(1).  I have a simpler argument that takes a very high minimum $x$.  Stirling's Approximation is probably the best way to go to simplify and improve the result.  If I find a better way through Stirling's Approximation, I will update my post.